# How data transfer happens between two VMs which are hosted on the same host?

Tags: virtualization

I would like to know about How data transfer happens between two VMs which are hosted on the same host? is it through the router or any other medium (like virtual router)?

Comment: what virtualization software do you use?

Comment: I have two type of virtualization software, 1. xencenter, 2. VMWare.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using VMware the communication between VMs is assured by a host only network adapter

[image: Host only network]

I think this network adapter works like a switch (Not a router, because it cant hold different sub-nets)

Comment: You're wrong, in [host-only mode the virtual machine only sees the host](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws3/doc/ws32_network6.html), the option that will work will be [NAT](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws3/doc/ws32_network10.html#1032424)

Comment: No I'm not, as you can see **"Host-only (Conect VMs internally in a private network), and"** But it can also connect the Host to this private network if you cheque **"Connet a host virtual adapter to this network"**

Comment: From the link of the host-only mode... "Host-only networking **provides a network connection between the virtual machine and the host computer**, using a virtual Ethernet adapter that is visible to the host operating system. This approach can be very useful if you need to set up an isolated virtual network."

Comment: From your reference for NAT :`" A host-only network uses a private virtual network. The host and all virtual machines configured for host-only networking are connected to the network through a virtual switch. "`

Comment: The NAT is used to connect VMs to your physical local network and the internet, see [here](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws3/doc/ws32_network21.html)

Comment: you're right mate, sorry for the misunderstanding. Could you change the answer (anything) to change the negative vote? Sorry again.

Comment: That's OK, even that the negative vote costs 2 points :( I think if you up-vote it will be canceled.